# Fortran call system('input.txt') run time modify

Tags: fortran, runtime, osx-yosemite, system-calls

I need to run a program that requires certain inputs that are listed in a `input.txt` file. I want to be able to call up this file when I execute the program so I can modify the `input.txt` file if needed before executing the rest of the code.

I'm running on Mac OS X.

What I have is:

```
call system('notes input.txt')
```

I get the following message :

> sh: notes: command not found

Is there a special way to call the app `notes`, or is my error somewhere else?

Comment: What is notes? What is the purpose of that call?

Comment: Related http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/concisely-starting-mac-os-apps-from-the-command-line

Comment: Also note that the standard way to execute a command line is offered by execute_command_line: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html

Comment: I meant to say textedit not notes. The purpose is, i have an input file that i pass into the program. The can change and therefor i want the input.txt file to open so i can modify it before its passed into the program. In windows using microsoft developer studio fortran power station it is done like this: call=systemqq("notepad inout.txt")

Answer (score 3):

you're not specifying a full filesystem path in the string ("notes input.txt") which the SYSTEM function sends to a command shell.  That means you're hoping there's a binary named "notes" somewhere in your shell's $PATH , and your shell is telling you that's not true.  The Notes app is not named "notes", and it doesn't live somewhere pointed to by the shell's $PATH.  That's why you get this error message.  Try passing to the shell the full path of both the binary you want to run, and the file you want to edit:

`CALL SYSTEM("/Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/Notes /path/to/input.txt")`

(NB: that path is where the Notes app lives on my Mac; YMMV.)

Comment: I said notes where i should've said textedit. I followed the formula and tried to search for the full path of TextEdit app with the "which" command, which didn't return anything . so I dragged and dropped the from finder to the terminal the textedit app and it gave me the directory path: /Applications/TextEdit.app my call command now:                                              call system("/Applications/TextEdit.app /path/to/input.txt") when executed my code it returns with the message sh: /Applications/TextEdit.app: is a directory.  Am I not passing the file into the app to open it?

Comment: `TextEdit.app` is a the application package directory (which you can't execute) - you have to find the actual binary inside.  Try `/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
call system("/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /path/to/input.text")
```

The `/Applications/TextEdit.app` location is a bit misleading as it is actually a folder. In Finder if you option-click on it you can select to view contents (Not sure of the exact wording of the option as I don't have my mac on me at the moment). Alternatively, `cd /Applications/TextEdit.app; ls` to view the contents. The executable should be stored in a subdirectory as shown above.

Comment: Ok so first this is the correct system call because it tells me it didn't find the file but that because i didn't put it into the directory. I can't move my file from the current directory because then th program won't execute at all. The .txt file along with the code has to be win the same directory.